# Magento CSS/JS not loading after upgrade to 1.8.1

Tags: css, magento

I just upgraded my Magento site from 1.6 to 1.8.1. After the update the website is unable to load CSS and JS. I checked the error log and it says this:

> [Tue Apr 22 16:40:30.616082 2014] [core:crit] [pid 27847:tid 140041728800512] (13)Permission denied: [client 60.240.167.112:59507] AH00529: /home/strictly/public_html/js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/strictly/public_html/js/' is executable,

I followed many people's advice and did these:

- Clear cache in var/cache folder
- web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url configurations are correct (they both point to the corrent URL)
- dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_css_files are both 0

Even after this the site loads very slowly, and when it loads it's not no CSS and JS. I check the behind-workings using Chrome's Inspect Elements button and I can see the CSS and JS files failing to load, each giving 404 not found error.

My guess is it has something to do with setting the correct permission for the JS and CSS folders/files. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thank you

Comment: Upgrading fails most probably when `Mage/core` files have been changed.

Comment: how you upgraded??..direct from 1.6 to 1.8?? ..you should do step by step like first 1.6 to 1.7 after that 1.7 to 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer.. I had to set the permission of skins folder to 755. After this, everything started working :)